# Llave primaria nula

Tags: base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Estoy usando phpMyAdmin, el problema es que me permite tener valores nulos en mi llave primaria cuando se supone que eso no es posible. ¿A alguien le ha pasado lo mismo?

```
CREATE TABLE `departamentos` (
 `numdepto` varchar(3)  NOT NULL,
 `nombredepto` varchar(20)  NULL,
 `presupuestodep` int(11) NULL,
 `numempgerente` varchar(4)  NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`numdepto`)
)
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, ve a [edit] tu pregunta y añade la definición de la tabla sobre la que estás validando la inserción. COMO TEXTO, sin capturas de pantalla. Así mismo, incluye la consulta que estás utilizando para probar. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: La definición de tabla que muestras no admitirá en ningún caso un valor `null` para la columna `numdepto`, primero porque es llave primaria, segundo porque la has definido con la restricción `NOT NULL`. Entonces, puede que tu tabla esté admitiendo un valor **vacío o en blanco, que no es lo mismo que `NULL`**. Sea como sea, pon un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable del problema y agrega los mensajes de error, si los hay.

Comment: A. Cedano inserte registros  a la tabla como normalmente se hace pero se me ocurrió dejar en blanco la parte de la llave primaria y si me inserta el registro y como dices al ser llave primaria no deberia permitirlo. Insert into departamentos values ('', 'Sistemas', 1000000,'E1')

Comment: Es lo que te acabo de decir, ahí tú estás insertando un valor en blanco en la llave primaria, **que no es lo mismo que `null`**. Si tú intentas algo así, verás que te salta un error: **`Insert into departamentos values (null, 'Sistemas', 1000000,'E1');`** Conviene que comprendas que esto: `''` no es igual a `null`  en ningún caso.

Answer (score 1):

Tu definición de tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE departamentos ( 
    numdepto varchar(3) NOT NULL, 
    nombredepto varchar(20) NULL, 
    presupuestodep int(11) NULL, 
    numempgerente varchar(4) NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (numdepto) );
```

No admitirá jamás un valor `NULL`, para la columna `numdepto`, por el hecho de ser la llave primaria. Y aunque no lo fuera, si tiene la restricción `NOT NULL`, tampoco recibirá un valor `NULL`.

Ahora bien, **`NULL` no es lo mismo que un valor *en blanco* o un valor vacío**.

Por tanto, esto funcionará:

```
insert into departamentos values ('', 'Sistemas', 1000000,'E1');
```

Pero esto no:

```
insert into departamentos values (null, 'Sistemas', 1000000,'E1');
```

Si tú quieres evitar la inserción de valores vacíos tienes dos opciones:

### Opción 1:

Si dispones de MySQL 8.0.16+ puedes hacer uso de `CHECK` en tu definición de tabla, para indicarle que rechace los valores en blanco ([consulta el Manual de Referencia para más detalles](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html)):

```
CREATE TABLE departamentos ( 
    numdepto varchar(3) NOT NULL, CHECK(TRIM(numdepto) > ''), 
    nombredepto varchar(20) NULL, 
    presupuestodep int(11) NULL, 
    numempgerente varchar(4) NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (numdepto) );
```

### Opción 2:

Si tu versión de MySQL es anterior a MySQL 8.0.16 puedes definir un [disparador (TRIGGER)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) que evite las inserciones cuando el valor para `numdepto` sea vacío:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trg_departamentos_empty_check
  BEFORE INSERT ON departamentos
  FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
          IF TRIM(NEW.numdepto) = '' THEN
              SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No se admiten valores en blanco';        
          END IF; 
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Con este TRIGGER definido, todos estos intentos o similares:

```
insert into departamentos values ('', 'Sistemas', 1000000,'E1');
insert into departamentos values (' ', 'Sistemas', 1000000,'E1');
insert into departamentos values ('  ', 'Sistemas', 1000000,'E1');
insert into departamentos values ('      ', 'Sistemas', 1000000,'E1');
```

Serán rechazados con el mensaje:

> Error: ER_SIGNAL_EXCEPTION: No se admiten valores en blanco

Aparte de esto, que conviene tener definido a nivel de base de datos, conviene controlar los valores vacíos, allí donde son recogidos (formularios, archivos, etc) para tener un código optimizado. Así, por ejemplo, desde el cliente no se enviarán datos al servidor para ser rechazados posteriormente, ahorrando recursos en todos los niveles.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos he logrado resolver el problema con la opcion que me dieron de agregar un check para que no me acepte valores vacios.

Comment: No contestes en el área de respuestas a menos que pongas la solución a tu problema inicial, ya que puede ser eliminada

Answer (score -1):

Cuando creas una tabla debes indicar que la PK es NOT NULL, por ejemplo:

```
create table example(){
  idTabla int primary key not null,
  otroCampo varchar(50) null
 }
```

Debes indicarlo explicitamente sino MySQL lo hace de manera implicita y silenciosa, aunque sea llave primaria si no se declara como NOT NULL, el gestor lo marcara como NULL.

Comment: Lo que dices no es para nada cierto. Una llave primaria nunca podrá ser `NULL`.

Comment: Las llaves primarias no pueden ser nulas, los índices sí. Quizá te confundiste por ese lado (:

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).